# AWS Cognito: Email verification with Link

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm using Cognito for User Management, and everything seems to work fine apart from email verification process.

I would like to build user journey similar to all other website: 
1) Fill registration form with user details
2) Receive an email with email verification link
3) Verify email address by clicking on the link

So far, I can only verify email by making user manually input verification code. This is slightly unusual. And some users find it easier to just click on the link.

On "Message customisation" page, there is a possibility to use "link" for message verification. But it is using "Amazon Cognito domain", which is exposing underlying technology to the end user.
Ideally I would like to use my own domain.

I'm trying to "Use own domain" at "App integration->Domain Name" tab, but getting "We didn’t find any AWS managed certificates for this region."

But I have added "AWS managed certificates" for my domain and verified it via DNS. It is appearing in "Certificate Manager" with status "Issued".

Have someone successfully managed to use "Your own domain" for email verification? What am I missing?

Thanks,
OM

Answer (score 8):

OK, I found what the problem was.
Thanks Mukti Arip, for pointing to documentation.

Documentation says, that Certificate needs to be registered in US East (N. Virginia), no matter where your Cognito user pool is located.

As soon as I registered certificate in N. Virginia it appeared in my Domain configuration.

Answer (score 4):

You can send verification email using your own domain if you have an SES verified identity. See in this link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-addresses-and-domains.html

Comment: Actually that was not what I was asking.
I'm able to send email from my own domain email address.

What I'd like to do is inside email body, I would like to include email verification link, that would point to my own domain.

Like for example:

To verify your email please click here: http://mydomain/auth/userId

Comment: Your backend service behind mydomain/auth/userId-user606621 link can call AdminUpdateUserAttributes request to AWS Cognito API to update email_verified attribute.

Comment: Yes, but my issue is: How do I include URL with custom domain inside email body?

By default Cognito sends verification code, and there is an option to change that to Link, but the link Cognito sends is exposing AWS domain.

I'm just trying to figure out how to use my own domain inside the email Cognito sends to verify user email

Comment: In Cognito User Pool console > App integration > Domain name, there is option to use your own domain. The doc is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-add-custom-domain.html

Comment: Exactly, when I try using it, I'm getting "We didn’t find any AWS managed certificates for this region."
But I did configured certificate, and it was verified by DNS.
It is appearing in "Certificate Manager" with status "Issued".

Comment: so does the url in the verify {{link}} have something like http://mydomain/myVerificationEndpoint?username=bla@foo.com&code=<code auto added by cognito> ? and then at that endpoint I do a sdk.confirmSignup() before redirecting to my app ?  aws docs so crappy in this area

Comment: is there a way to use a link rather than a code in the "invitation" message? I have found the possibility to use a link ONLY for the 'verification' message, which is sent to retrieve a forgotten password. But there is choice when it comes to the 'inivitation' message...